# How to build GAE application for SDK v1.7.5 (with Maven)

Tags: google-app-engine, maven

I'm trying to make GAE 1.7.5 work with Maven:

```
<properties>
    <gae.version>1.7.5</gae.version>
    <gae-runtime.version>1.7.5.1</gae-runtime.version>
    <maven.gae.plugin.version>0.9.6</maven.gae.plugin.version>
</properties>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.gae.plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
            <unpackVersion>${gae.version}</unpackVersion>
            <serverId>appengine.google.com</serverId>
            <appDir>${webappDirectory}</appDir>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
                <artifactId>gae-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>${gae-runtime.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

However there is this problem:

```
[WARNING] The POM for net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:jar:0.9.6 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.6: Plugin net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:jar:0.9.6
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
```

Then eventually, will end into BUILD FAILURE.

How to build my GAE against version `1.7.5` with Maven?

Comment: Why 1.7.5 and not trying that for the latest version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the App Engine Maven Plugin](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven). We also have [a guestbook sample app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-java) on github.

Answer (score 0):

The official appengine-maven-plugin supports 1.7.6, you could use the 1.7.5 version if you want, but 1.7.6 is current now.